# JQuery Calculator: can not get operators to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a JQuery calculator.
However, to get my operators buttons to work (+,-,x)
i need to be able to store the current value to enter another value
and i am not sure how to do this.
The function dataOperation was my main idea-line.
But for some reason i still can get it to work properly

```js
function removeNumbers() {
    $(".current-operand").html('');
}

function passInt() {
    $('.current-operand').append(parseInt($(this).html()));
}

function dataOperation() {
    $('.previous-operand').html($(this).html());
    var operation = $(".data-operation").val();
    if (operation == '+') {

        getCurrentValue();
        var result = parseFloat($(".current-operand").val()) + 'samplevalue';

    }
    if (operation == '=') {
        $(".current-operand").html(result);
    }
}



function getCurrentValue() {
    var currentValue = $(".current-operand").val();
    removeNumbers();
    return currentValue;
}

function init() {
    $(".data-number").click(passInt);
    $(".data-allclear").click(removeNumbers);
    $(".data-operation").click(dataOperation);

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

```css
            *, *::before, *::after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            
            .calculator-grid {
                display: grid;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
                min-height: 100vh;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
                grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
            }
            
            .span-two {
                grid-column: span 2;
            }
            
            .output {
                grid-column: 1 / -1;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-end;
                justify-content: space-around;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 10px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                word-break: break-all;
            }
            
            .output .previous-operand {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }
            .output .current-operand {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
            
            
            
            
            .calculator-grid > button {
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border: 1px solid white;
                outline: none;
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            .calculator-grid button:hover {
                filter: brightness(110%);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="span-two data-allclear">AC</button>
    <button class="data-delete">DEL</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">1</button>
    <button class="data-number">2</button>
    <button class="data-number">3</button>
    <button class="data-operation">*</button>
    <button class="data-number">4</button>
    <button class="data-number">5</button>
    <button class="data-number">6</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">7</button>
    <button class="data-number">8</button>
    <button class="data-number">9</button>
    <button class="data-operation">-</button>
    <button class="data-number">.</button>
    <button class="data-number">0</button>
    <button class="span-two data-equals">=</button>
</div>
```

When clicking any operant function, the current number should be stored and dissapear for a second value to be entered which will also be stored

Comment: Can you save into code snippet that we can run your code?

Comment: check this link for your reference  https://codepen.io/apguan/pen/zBvMdJ

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code ist that you don't access the fields wrong. You'd like to use the existing html content. The code uses .val(), so you would get the value of an input field but it is a simple text. So you need .html();. Also the result of getCurrentValue was not used

```js
function removeNumbers() {
    $(".current-operand").html('');
}

function passInt() {
    $('.current-operand').append(parseInt($(this).html()));
}

function dataOperation(e) {
    var operation = $(this).html();
    var oldValue = getCurrentValue();
    var existingValue = $('#previous-operand').html()
    if (operation == '+') {
        console.log(existingValue);
        var result = existingValue + parseFloat($(".current-operand").html()) + operation + oldValue;
    }

    if (operation == '=') {
        $(".current-operand").html(result);
    }

    $('.previous-operand').html(existingValue + oldValue + $(this).html());
}



function getCurrentValue() {
    var currentValue = $("#current-operand").html();
    removeNumbers();
    return currentValue;
}

function init() {
    $(".data-number").click(passInt);
    $(".data-allclear").click(removeNumbers);
    $(".data-operation").click(dataOperation);

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

```css
            *, *::before, *::after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            
            .calculator-grid {
                display: grid;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
                min-height: 100vh;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
                grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
            }
            
            .span-two {
                grid-column: span 2;
            }
            
            .output {
                grid-column: 1 / -1;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-end;
                justify-content: space-around;
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 10px;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                word-break: break-all;
            }
            
            .output .previous-operand {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }
            .output .current-operand {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
            
            
            
            
            .calculator-grid > button {
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border: 1px solid white;
                outline: none;
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            .calculator-grid button:hover {
                filter: brightness(110%);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div id="previous-operand" class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div id="current-operand" class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="span-two data-allclear">AC</button>
    <button class="data-delete">DEL</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">1</button>
    <button class="data-number">2</button>
    <button class="data-number">3</button>
    <button class="data-operation">*</button>
    <button class="data-number">4</button>
    <button class="data-number">5</button>
    <button class="data-number">6</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">7</button>
    <button class="data-number">8</button>
    <button class="data-number">9</button>
    <button class="data-operation">-</button>
    <button class="data-number">.</button>
    <button class="data-number">0</button>
    <button class="span-two data-equals">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The basic function of adding the text to the previous-operand on + worked. I've fixed it so you can do things like 1 + 2 + 3. All things only work if using +. Calculation is not done.